# How to translate "Pescatarian" into Esperanto?

Tags: translation, culture

In analogy to the word formation of *vegetarano* - *legomo*, can I have *pesketarano* - *fiŝo* which does not use the corresponding root of *fish* in Esperanto? Or *fiŝ-vegetarano* should be preferred?

I wrote a small paragraph for explaining it:

> "Fiŝ-vegetarismo”(Pesketarismo) estas la maniero de sekvi dieton, dum kiu estas evitata manĝado de viandoj krom fiŝaĵoj.

Does it make sense?

Sincere thanks.

<sub>See the wiki page for [Pescetarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pescetarianism).</sub>

<sub>Updated: I have changed the word in the description from *-arano* to *-ismo* to indicate Pescatarianism for clearer understanding.</sub>

Comment: I think the "fiŝ-vegetarano" or "perketarano" should be the person themselves, right, not so much "la maniero"? I know this is not what the question itself was about, so I'm adding it as a comment.

Comment: ”Veget” fakte estas radiko rilata al plantoj. Vegetaranoj mangxas ne nur legomojn, sed ankaux fruktojn, nuksojn, grenojn ktp.

Comment: In fact "vegetar-" is an independent root, officialized after "veget-".

Comment: Since there are so many possible diets in the world, I wouldn't expect all possible diets to have a one-word translation into the international language. "I am a pescatarian" could be expressed "mi ne manĝas viandon, sed ja fiŝaĵon."

Comment: @VincentOostelbos  have changed the word in the description from *-arano* to *-ismo* to indicate Pescatarianism to make it clearer :P btw does the description make sense to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**fiŝ-vegetarano** is preferable as combining two words into one by ommitig a part of the radix is not done in Esperanto. Also it would introduce an unnecessary neologism. One might think of better terms like **fiŝescepta vegetarano**, but **fiŝvegetarano** is fine, not misunderstandable.

Comment: Nothing is "not misunderstandable" (everything can be misunderstood.)

Comment: Dankon. Mi provos uzi estontece :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your explanation makes sense.